# How to decode the Netconf messages captured by Wireshark?

Tags: ssh, wireshark, netconf, confd

My Netconf client communicates with a Confd Netconf server over SSH. I see encrypted packets (of type SSHv2 and TCP) captured by Wireshark whenever the client communicates with the server. How to decode these packets?

Comment: This question has already been answered on a sister site: [https://superuser.com/questions/1099780/how-to-decrypt-ssh-packets-captured-on-wireshark-tool-on-a-suse-linux-box](https://superuser.com/questions/1099780/how-to-decrypt-ssh-packets-captured-on-wireshark-tool-on-a-suse-linux-box). It's not supported by Wireshark.

Comment: Thanks @predi. The sister site response says that "This is also not possible unless the shared secret is extracted from the SSH server or client". Does it mean that we can decrypt the SSH packets if we know the shared secret?